# How can I write to the instance on the parent class from a subclass in Django models?

Tags: django, django-models

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849271/how-do-i-collect-multiple-django-models-together-into-a-single-list/10849545)...

I have two primary models for my blog, `Article` and `Link`, and both are subclasses of `Post`. Simplifying a little, they look something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)

class Article(Post):
    feature_image = models.FileField(upload_to='feature_images')

class Link(Post):
    link = models.URLField(verify_exists=True)
```

I want to collect over both Articles and Links, so in my view, I run `Post.objects.order_by('post_date')` and presto, I get the whole list--but only with the fields that are on `Post`. If I want to use the link in a `Link` instance, I can't.

I have the primary key, so I should be able to do something like `Link.objects.get(pk=item.pk)` and be set--but I'd have to know if this was a `Link` or an `Article`.

Can I create a `post_type` property on the parent model and write to it with the correct model name from the children?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a totally different way in the end, by writing a custom manager for Post:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def __get_final(self, pk):
        for k in Post.__subclasses__():
            if k.objects.filter(pk=pk).exists():
                return k.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return None

    def __subclass_queryset(self, qs):
        collection = []
        for item in qs:
            collection.append(self.__get_final(item.pk))
        return collection

    def all(self):
        return self.__subclass_queryset(super(PostManager, self).all())
```

Now `Post.objects.all()` (or any other QuerySet operation I add to the manager, like `order_by`), and I'll get back a list of all of the objects, with their full set of specific fields. (I then reset the manager on the subclasses, so they're not saddled with these extra queries for routine operations.)